# Need help with the proof of the following theorem about orders

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Theorem 4-7. If any integer belongs to $t\pmod p$, then exactly $\varphi(t)$ incongruent numbers belong to $t\pmod p$

Proof: Assume that $\operatorname{ord}_p a=t$. Then by theorem 4-4, $t\mid (p-1)$, and hence by fermat's theorem and euler's theorem, there are exactly $t$ roots of the congruence $x^t \equiv 1 \pmod p$. But all the numbers $a,a^2,\ldots,a^t$ are roots of this congruence and and since they are incongruent $\pmod p$, they are the only roots. **By theorem 4-6, the powers of a which belong to $t\pmod p$ are the numbers $a^n$ with $(n,t)=1$, $1 \leq n \leq t$, and there are precisely $\varphi(t)$ of these numbers.**

Theorem 4-4: For every a prime to $m$, $\operatorname{ord}_m a\mid\varphi(m)$
Theorem 4-6: If $\operatorname{ord}_m a=t$, then $\operatorname{ord}_m a^n = t/(n,t)$

I highlighted the claims I can't understand.

Comment: By $t(mod p)$ do you mean $\{a \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a \equiv t \mod p \}$?

Comment: By 4.6, $\ a^n\ $ has order $\,t/(n,t)\,$ so $\,a^n\,$ has order $t\iff t/(n,t)=t\iff (n,t)=1\ $

Comment: @JasonM. I think it means all the numbers a such that $a^t \equiv 1(mod \text{ } p)$ where t is the smallest positive integer

Comment: @Bill Dubuque. How does that relate to $\varphi(t)$?

Comment: I understand, that guarantees $ord_p{a^n} =t$, but how do we know there are $\varphi(t)$ of these numbers.

Comment: Do I just have to believe it's magic at my current level?

Comment: That's the definition of $\,\varphi(t),\,$ i.e. the number of $\,n < t\,$ that are coprime to $\,t.\ $

Comment: Several times you wrote "(mod \text{ } p)".  And maybe ten times in recent days I've seen others use that same sequence of characters in MathJax code.  Where is that coming from?  Are you using one of those web pages that purport to write MathJax code for you?  Where you you find such pages?  That is really terrible MathJax coding.  I cleaned it up. $\qquad$